# Why do I have to do captchas while logged in?

Tags: discussion, support, answers

A few days ago, I tried to submit an answer and was surprised when a captcha popup appeared, requiring me to tick an "I'm not a robot" box and possibly pick out some pictures before continuing.

**Why should we have to do captchas while logged in?**

The system clearly recognised that I was logged in to my SE account. I've been around on this site for over a year and have got nearly all the rep-based privileges; why should I need to prove I'm not a robot at this stage?

<sub>(The result of this delay was that another user posted a near-identical answer first and got the accepted answer instead of</sub>
<sup>me. However, this isn't the first time it's happened.)</sup>

If it makes a difference, my internet connection at the time was very slow and dodgy. I'd already tried to submit the answer a couple of times and just got an error message since the page wasn't loading. The captcha was also very slow to work. In the end I opened another window and posted the answer there, and succeeded without needing to complete a captcha test.

Comment: When my Internet is crapping out, *Google* makes me do captchas for web searches.

Comment: "I'd already tried to submit the answer a couple of times " because you were behaving like a spambot.

Comment: @phantom42 Well, I've never been so insulted :-P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Being a high-rep, logged-in user doesn't automatically solve the problems CAPTCHA is aiming to solve. Although it certainly means you weren't *intended* to be a spambot, it doesn't preclude you from *becoming* one; what if some malware got onto your computer and hijacked your account info?

Personally, I'm of the opinion that high-rep users should have *more* CAPTCHAs, simply because we can do more damage if our accounts are compromised. But, as it stands, we already get less; per the [Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide/164900#164900), 10k+ users get CAPTCHAs on:

- Your second question posted within 30 seconds
- Your second answer posted within 30 seconds
- Your second edit within 10 seconds, or if it takes you less than 5 seconds to edit

Sub-10K users are limited on the same actions, but the numbers are generally doubled<sup>1</sup>.

I don't think anyone is going to argue that CAPTCHAs are a perfect system; I'm certainly not trying to. But they do solve a problem and, as [Jeff said in a blog post](http://blog.codinghorror.com/designing-for-evil/) (emphasis his):

> When you design your software, **work under the assumption that some of your users will be evil**
>
> *[...]*
>
> Because when good is dumb, evil will always triumph.

---

<sup>1</sup> The major exception to this is on answering; users with less than 125 rep can only post one answer every 3 minutes, so they don't trip an additional CAPTCHA.

The other exception is on short edits; all users get a CAPTCHA on edits that take less than five seconds

Comment: I was going to say what @user14111 said.

Comment: I've never had a captcha ever on any SE. I'm guessing noscript & FF are keeping them away from me... yet if it is that easy to circumvent it's not really effective - or I'm missing out on site features without realising it :P

Comment: @BMWurm Well, ideally a real user should *never* see a CAPTCHA; I've only ever seen one once (except on Data.SE, where I see them constantly because I don't bother to log in). So if you're not seeing them, then they're either working perfectly or failing spectacularly

Comment: I got a captcha again just now, despite being a ***mod*** this time. Guess SE just won't accept that I'm human ...